# Go back to a symbolic expression to evaluate derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbols

I have the following code.

```
(********************************)
(*USER INTERFACE*) 

(*CHOOSE FILTER ORDER BY CHANGING VALUE OF k*)
k = 2; 

(*INSERT VECTOR OF NORMALIZED CONDUCTANCES AND INDUCTANCES*)
Rin = 1;
Rout = 1; (* normalized value do not change for now *)
L = {Sqrt[2]}; 
CC = {Sqrt[2]};
(*PART 1 - DETERMINING THE FILTER TRANSFER FUNCTION *) 
ZL = s*L;
ZC = 1/(s*CC);
ZL[[1]] = ZL[[1]] + Rin;
If[Mod[k, 2] == 0, x = k/2, x = (k + 1)/2];
LCMatrix = 
  Table[{{1 + ZL[[i]]/ZC[[i]], ZL[[i]]}, {1/ZC[[i]], 1}}, {i, 1, x}];
LCLadderMatrix = LCMatrix[[1]];
For[i = 2, i <= x, i++, 
  LCLadderMatrix = Simplify[LCLadderMatrix . LCMatrix[[i]]]];
LCLadderMatrix // MatrixForm
aux = Simplify[
   Solve[Vi == 
     LCLadderMatrix[[1]][[1]]*Vo + LCLadderMatrix[[1]][[2]]*Vo/Rout, 
    Vo]];
TFilter = Simplify[Vo/Vi /. aux[[1]]]
```

My problem now is that I have to evaluate derivatives of TFilter in terms of parameters Rin, L[[1]], C[[1]], etc. Is there any way I can go back to a symbolic expression?

Comment: Don't use "=", simply define a replacement rule that you call numeric values.

Comment: Any reason to think the first few lines are relevant? It’ll really piss off someone who’s trying to help you if they don’t notice the effect they’ll have on their session…. Post only what’s necessary. That’s my advice.

Comment: @MichaelE2 you are right sorry!