# Replace Array on symbolic expression

Tags: symbolic, list-manipulation

Following my previous question: [Go back to a symbolic expression to evaluate derivative](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257567/go-back-to-a-symbolic-expression-to-evaluate-derivative?noredirect=1#comment642257_257567)

I've changed my code to keep the symbolic expression.

My question now is if there is a way of replacing L1 and CC2 by changing L and C to numerical vectors. This is because I want to insert this values in vector form instead of one by one, as this program is supposed to increase in size.

```
(********************************)
(*CHOOSE FILTER ORDER BY CHANGING VALUE OF k*)
k = 2; 

L = {L1}; 
CC = {CC2};

(*PART 1 - DETERMINING THE FILTER TRANSFER FUNCTION *) 
ZL = s*L;
ZC = 1/(s*CC);
ZL[[1]] = ZL[[1]] + Rin;
If[Mod[k, 2] == 0, x = k/2, x = (k + 1)/2];
LCMatrix = 
  Table[{{1 + ZL[[i]]/ZC[[i]], ZL[[i]]}, {1/ZC[[i]], 1}}, {i, 1, x}];
LCLadderMatrix = LCMatrix[[1]];
For[i = 2, i <= x, i++, 
  LCLadderMatrix = Simplify[LCLadderMatrix . LCMatrix[[i]]]];
LCLadderMatrix // MatrixForm

aux = Simplify[
   Solve[Vi == 
     LCLadderMatrix[[1]][[1]]*Vo + LCLadderMatrix[[1]][[2]]*Vo/Rout, 
    Vo]];
TFilter = Simplify[Vo/Vi /. aux[[1]]]

DenTFilter = Expand[Denominator[TFilter]];
DenTFilter = DenTFilter /. s -> I*wn;
RealDen = ComplexExpand[Re[DenTFilter]];

ImagDen = ComplexExpand[Im[DenTFilter]];

Gain = Numerator[TFilter]/Sqrt[RealDen^2 + ImagDen^2]

(*INSERT VECTOR OF NORMALIZED CONDUCTANCES AND INDUCTANCES*)
Rin = 1;
Rout = 1; (* normalized value do not change for now *)
L = {Sqrt[2]}; 
CC = {Sqrt[2]};
Gain
```

Comment: Please reduce your code down to the minimum describing your specific problem. Don't make us figure out what all your code does to help you!

Comment: Maybe simply `Gain/.{L1->Sqrt[2], CC2->Sqrt[2]}` ?